# Checking .NewRecord property on sub-subform - Invalid Reference

Tags: ms-access-2010

I am running a vba subroutine to check the status of a sub-subform and see if it is a new or existing record but I get an error message telling me "Run-time error '2455': You entered an expression that has an invalid reference to the property Form/Report." I started with this code:

If Forms!MainForm!Subform1.Form!Subform2.Form.NewRecord then
debug.print "New"
Else
debug.print "Existing"
End If

I also tried:

If Forms!MainForm.Form!Subform1.Form!Subform2.NewRecord then

If Forms!MainForm!Subform1!Subform2.Form.NewRecord then

If Forms!MainForm!Subform1!Subform2.NewRecord then

But still no luck. I've always found [this page](http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm) very helpful in referencing things in Access but this time it doesn't seem to be enough. Am I just missing something very simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```vb
If Me!NameOfSubformControl1.Form!NameOfSubformControl2.Form.NewRecord Then 
     Debug.Print "New" 
Else 
     Debug.Print "Existing" 
End If
```

Comment: Ah, of course. It's all too often the simple things that stymie us. Thank you for your answer. Ticked and upvoted.